# Why I do get another version of table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I'm reading about kable in R Markdown and I found something incomprehensible.

On the R site of kable function I see code:

> For R Markdown documents, kable() uses the pipe format for tables by
> default, which looks like this:

[image]

However when I'm trying to run same code what I have is:

[image]

I wonder why. Could you please explain to me what I'm doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Like Brian answered below, wouldn't worry about the pipe, if the pipe is by default, you wouldn't have to type it anyways, kable is made to be simple. Kable is best for HTML rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. Try typing `knitr::kable(head(mtcars[,1:4]))` straight into the console and you will see the pipe format. Since you are evaluating it inside an r chunk, the pipe format gets rendered into HTML. The kable function is a shortcut; writing all those `|:` pipe characters manually would be cumbersome.

```
> knitr::kable(head(mtcars[,1:4]))


|                  |  mpg| cyl| disp|  hp|
|:-----------------|----:|---:|----:|---:|
|Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6|  160| 110|
|Mazda RX4 Wag     | 21.0|   6|  160| 110|
|Datsun 710        | 22.8|   4|  108|  93|
|Hornet 4 Drive    | 21.4|   6|  258| 110|
|Hornet Sportabout | 18.7|   8|  360| 175|
|Valiant           | 18.1|   6|  225| 105|
```